# Renew Loading JSON Repeat Last Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I made a JSON script that bring posts from JSON page and when the user scroll down I renew loading to bring more posts and it works great but the problem is when the JSON load the first time it repeat the last post. here is a [live demo](http://dte-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/json-demo/index-1.html) of the script. 
How you can see when you scroll down to the end the script show more posts but it is repeating the last post which called "Automatic Slideshow for Blogger with 3D Gallery".

HTML CODE

```
<div id="result-container">
    <ol></ol>
    <span class="loading">Memuat...</span>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
#result-container {
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:50px auto;
  font:normal normal 12px 'Trebuchet MS',Trebuchet,Geneva,Arial,Sans-Serif;
}

#result-container ol {
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 0;
  background-color:#B5D68C;
}

#result-container li {
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 0;
  list-style:none;
}

#result-container li:nth-child(even) {background-color:#A2C179}

#result-container li a {
  display:block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#396B18;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#result-container li a:hover {
  background-color:#396B18;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#result-container .loading {
  display:block;
  height:26px;
  font:normal bold 11px/26px Arial,Sans-Serif;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#B75A6F;
  border-top:2px solid #222;
}

#result-container .loading.the-end {background-color:#666}
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var widget_config = {
    home_page: 'http://www.dte.web.id', // Your blog homepage
    container_id: 'result-container', // ID of the result container
    script_id: 'load-on-scroll-end-script', // ID of the asynchronous script
    max_result: 25, // Max result post at once script loading
    end_text: 'Habis' // End text if all posts has been loaded
};

var elem = document.getElementById(widget_config.container_id),
    inner = elem.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0],
    loading = elem.getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
    start = 0, // Dynamic start-index
    max = widget_config.max_result;

function grabList(json) {
    var list = json.feed.entry, link, skeleton = "";
    if (list !== undefined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < list[i].link.length; j++) {
                if (list[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                    link = list[i].link[j].href;
                }
            }
            skeleton += '<li><a href="' + link + '">' + list[i].title.$t + '</a></li>';
        }
        inner.innerHTML += skeleton; // Insert the list to the container
        loading.style.display = "none"; // Hide the loading indicator
    } else {
        // If the JSON is empty (list == undefined),
        // add a new class to the loading indicator called `the-end`
        loading.className += ' the-end';
        // Replace the loading indicator text into `fully loaded!` for the example
        loading.textContent = widget_config.end_text;
    }
}

// Make an indirect script loader with two parameters: start-index and max-result post
function updateScript(a, b) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.id = widget_config.script_id;
        script.src = widget_config.home_page + '/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&start-index=' + a + '&max-results=' + b + '&callback=grabList';
    // If there is an old script in the document...
    if (document.getElementById(widget_config.script_id)) {
        var oldScript = document.getElementById(widget_config.script_id);
        // Remove the old script, and replace with the new one that has an updated start-index value
        oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);
    }
    head.appendChild(script);
}

// Start loading the callback script with start-index of 1
updateScript(1, max);

// When the container is being scrolled...
elem.onscroll = function() {
    // ... check the scroll distance
    if ((this.scrollTop + this.offsetHeight) == inner.offsetHeight) {
        // If the distance equal to the height of the inner container...
        start++; // Increase the start value by one
        // then load the new script with an updated start-index
        updateScript(start*max, max);
        // and show the loading indicator
        loading.style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the API for the link is starting on index 1 which is not taken into consideration when fetching the next page.

Try `updateScript(start*max + 1, max);`

Comment: Thank you so such I really don't know how to thank you.